# How can I remove or replace all punctuation characters from a String?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I have a string composed of words, some of which contain punctuation, which I would like to remove, but I have been unable to figure out how to do this.

For example if I have something like

```
var words = "Hello, this : is .. a  string?"
```

I would like to  be able to create an array with

```
"[Hello, this, is, a, string]"
```

My original thought was to use something like `words.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet()` to remove any characters I didn't want but that would only take characters off the ends.

I thought maybe I could iterate through the string with something in the vein of

```
for letter in words {
    if NSCharacterSet.punctuationCharacterSet.characterIsMember(letter){
        //remove that character from the string
    }
}
```

but I'm unsure how to remove the character from the string. I'm sure there are some problems with the way that if statement is set up, as well, but it shows my thought process.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Xcode 11.4 • Swift 5.2 or later**

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var words: [SubSequence] {
        split(whereSeparator: \.isLetter.negation)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Bool {
    var negation: Bool { !self }
}
```

---

```
let sentence = "Hello, this : is .. a  string?"
let words = sentence.words  // ["Hello", "this", "is", "a", "string"]
```

Comment: I ended up using a mixture of a few of these solutions to get it to work, but this one helped me get the last error I had fixed. I ended up creating an NSMutableCharacterset which was alphanumericCharacterSet plus " ". Then I used the solution here to get what I needed without having extra spaces.

Answer (score 7):

`String` has a `enumerateSubstringsInRange()` method.
With the `.ByWords` option, it detects word boundaries and
punctuation automatically:

**Swift 3/4:**

```
let string = "Hello, this : is .. a \"string\"!"
var words : [String] = []
string.enumerateSubstrings(in: string.startIndex..<string.endIndex,
                                  options: .byWords) {
                                    (substring, _, _, _) -> () in
                                    words.append(substring!)
}
print(words) // [Hello, this, is, a, string]
```

**Swift 2:**

```
let string = "Hello, this : is .. a \"string\"!"
var words : [String] = []
string.enumerateSubstringsInRange(string.characters.indices,
    options: .ByWords) {
        (substring, _, _, _) -> () in
        words.append(substring!)
}
print(words) // [Hello, this, is, a, string]
```

Comment: Thanks for enumerateSubstringsInRange & .ByWords. Very interesting.

Comment: This code needs to be updated for swift 4 or may be swift 3

Comment: @InderKumarRathore: Updated for Swift 3. (It should work in Swift 4 as well, I'll check that later) – Thanks for the notice!

Comment: @MartinR Lol! I was about to update your answer by just having information from your another answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39534217/468724, but you updated it before me. Btw this works for swift 4. Thanks mate for the quick response :)

Answer (score 5):

This works with Xcode 8.1, Swift 3:

First define general-purpose extension for filtering by `CharacterSet`:

```
extension String {
  func removingCharacters(inCharacterSet forbiddenCharacters:CharacterSet) -> String 
{
    var filteredString = self
    while true {
      if let forbiddenCharRange = filteredString.rangeOfCharacter(from: forbiddenCharacters)  {
        filteredString.removeSubrange(forbiddenCharRange)
      }
      else {
        break
      }
    }

    return filteredString
  }
}
```

Then filter using punctuation:

```
let s:String = "Hello, world!"
s.removingCharacters(inCharacterSet: CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters) // => "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

NSScaner way:

```
let words = "Hello, this : is .. a  string?"

//
let scanner = NSScanner(string: words)
var wordArray:[String] = []
var word:NSString? = ""

while(!scanner.atEnd) {
  var sr = scanner.scanCharactersFromSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), intoString: &word)
  if !sr {
    scanner.scanLocation++
    continue
  }
  wordArray.append(String(word!))
}

println(wordArray)
```

Comment: This does not split on space character.

Comment: @halex Sorry for the wrong post. I've modified my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
let charactersToRemove = NSCharacterSet.punctuationCharacterSet().invertedSet
let aWord = "".join(words.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(charactersToRemove))
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to filter characters from a set and obtain an array of words is by using the array's `filter` and `reduce` methods. It's not as compact as other answers, but it shows how the same result can be obtained in a different way.

First define an array of the characters to remove:

```
let charactersToRemove = Set(Array(".:?,"))
```

next convert the input string into an array of characters:

```
let arrayOfChars = Array(words)
```

Now we can use `reduce` to build a string, obtained by appending the elements from `arrayOfChars`, but skipping all the ones included in `charactersToRemove`:

```
let filteredString = arrayOfChars.reduce("") {
    let str = String($1)
    return $0 + (charactersToRemove.contains($1) ? "" : str)
}
```

This produces a string without the punctuation characters (as defined in `charactersToRemove`).

The last 2 steps:

split the string into an array of words, using the blank character as separator:

```
let arrayOfWords = filteredString.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
```

last, remove all empty elements:

```
let finalArrayOfWords = arrayOfWords.filter { $0.isEmpty == false }
```