# How to compare Range<String.Index> and DefaultBidirectionalIndices<String.CharacterView>?

Tags: swift, range, swift3

This comparison worked in Swift 2 but doesn't anymore in Swift 3:

`let myStringContainsOnlyOneCharacter = mySting.rangeOfComposedCharacterSequence(at: myString.startIndex) == mySting.characters.indices`

How do I compare Range and DefaultBidirectionalIndices?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/39104563/1187415, which contains a `isSingleComposedCharacter` definition for both  Swift 2 and Swift 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [SE-0065 – A New Model for Collections and Indices](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md)

> In Swift 2, `collection.indices` returned a `Range<Index>`, but because a range is a simple pair of indices and indices can no longer be advanced on their own, `Range<Index>` is no longer iterable.
>
> In order to keep code like the above working, `Collection` has acquired an associated Indices type that is always iterable, ...

Since `rangeOfComposedCharacterSequence` returns a *range* of
character indices, the solution is *not* to use `indices`, but
`startIndex..<endIndex`:

```
myString.rangeOfComposedCharacterSequence(at: myString.startIndex) 
== myString.startIndex..<myString.endIndex
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `String` nor `String.CharacterView` does not have a concise method returning `Range<String.Index>` or something comparable to it.

You may need to create a Range explicitly with range operator:

```
let myStringContainsOnlyOneCharacter = myString.rangeOfComposedCharacterSequence(at: myString.startIndex)
    == myString.startIndex..<myString.endIndex
```

Or compare only upper bound, in your case:

```
let onlyOne = myString.rangeOfComposedCharacterSequence(at: myString.startIndex).upperBound
    == myString.endIndex
```

Comment: OOPs (again), did not see your answer ... – You might want to add the reference to SE-0065, then I can delete mine.

Comment: @MartinR, your answer has a better reference. Please do not hesitate to post a better answer.