# inout String is not convertible to String in Swift 3 range

Tags: swift, swift3

I have the following code that works fine in Swift 2:

```
let myModifiedString = myOriginalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "#(?:\\S+)\\s?",
            with: "",
            options: .regularExpression,
            range: Range(myOriginalString.characters.indices))
```

I am busy upgrading my code to Swift 3, however, and I get the error 'inout String' is not convertible to type 'String'.

The error occurs on myOriginalString.characters.indices.

I saw that Swift 3 made some changes to how ranges are implemented and also to some String functionality. I just can't seem to find a succinct solution to resolve the problem and convert this statement to proper Swift 3 syntax. What is the proper Swift 3 syntax for the statement?

Comment: Essentially the same issue as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533523/how-to-compare-rangestring-index-and-defaultbidirectionalindicesstring-charac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 3, `indices` property has become a Collection of Index, and not any more a sort of Range. If you want a Range of Index representing the whole String, you need to write something like this:

```
let myModifiedString = myOriginalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "#(?:\\S+)\\s?",
                                                             with: "",
                                                             options: .regularExpression,
                                                             range: myOriginalString.startIndex..<myOriginalString.endIndex)
```