# Swift split substring based on word wrap

Tags: swift, string, algorithm

junior developer here. I am currently trying to achieve a substring that is split every n characters of a String.

This is my code for the function

```
public func split(every: Int) -> [String] {
    var result = [String]()

    for i in stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: every) {
        let startIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
        let endIndex = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: every, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex
        result.append(String(self[startIndex..<endIndex]))
    }
    return result
}
```

The above code works as expected. But there is one lacking from the code above, which is the word wrapping. Here is the sample String

```
let itemName = "Japanese Matcha SM w RB -L Special Edition And Americano MS w Brown Sugar Limited Edition"
print(itemName.split(every: 26))
```

The result will be

```
["Japanese Matcha SM w RB -L", " Special Edition And Ameri", "cano MS w Brown Sugar Limi", "ted Edition"]
```

Notice the

```
[" Special Edition And Ameri"], ["cano MS w Brown Sugar Limi"]
```

I am trying to figure out how to do the word wrap algorithm based on every n character, but couldn't find any clue.

For example, from above case, how to generate the array becomes,

```
[" Special Edition And"], ["Americano MS w Brown"], ["Sugar"]
```

So as you can see, the algorithm might check whether every n characters has a word that is being cut out (dynamic check based on the n characters), hence will move the cut word into the next array.

So in that case, the algorithm will cleverly bypass the every n character, might be less, but not more than n characters, if there is any word not being wrapped.

Is my explanation clear? Can anyone guide me please? Thanks

Comment: Well, your algorithm does exactly what you describe it should do: splits a String on every n-th character. Splitting on words is a completely different problem that's also contradicting splitting on every n-th character. So what is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Your code do what you tel it to do. But if you wanna remove front and last spaces you may have write a loop function by your self. Eg. get first index check for space, if so advanced by one and check for space until you got a letter. Then add 26 to that index and check last space, etc. it’s not as hard as it sounds

Comment: Hello David, thanks for the respond. I have edited the question :)

Comment: And what should the algorithm do when a specific word longer than the number of maximum characters allowed?

Comment: Use `enumerateSubstrings()` with the `.byWords` option ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29668468)), count the characters in each substring, and decide when to start a new chunk.

Comment: @DávidPásztor, if the last world already exceed the n characters, then it will be moved on to the next array. Further explanation has been added to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is some simple implementation of this algorithm, you can start with that. 
First we cut string by words, then add them to temporary string until we meet characters limit.

```
let itemName = "Japanese Matcha SM w RB -L Special Edition And Americano MS w Brown Sugar Limited Edition"

let table = itemName.split(separator: " ")

let limit = 26
var tempString = ""

var finalResult: [String] = []

for item in table {
    tempString += item + " "

    if tempString.count >= limit {
        finalResult.append(tempString)
        tempString = ""
    }
}

print(finalResult)
```

Comment: HI Lu, thanks for the help. I cannot split by word, because i need to count the space as the string count as well

Comment: but tempString counts spaces as you can see algorithm adds space back to it

Comment: Ok got it. I will try to do the checking from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```swift
extension String {
    func split(every: Int) -> [String] {
        var result = [String]()
        let words = self.split(separator: " ")
        var line = String(words.first!)

        words.dropFirst().forEach { word in
            let word = " " + String(word)
            if line.count + word.count <= every {
                line.append(word)
            } else {
                result.append(line)
                line = word
            }
        }
        result.append(line)
        return result
    }
}
```